# Preventing Files from Being Overwritten

Tags: git

I have files that I don't want pushed or overwritten.  They are in my .gitignore file.  When other developers push their copies of these files, my local copies are overwritten.  How do I prevent this?  Since I added these files to my .gitignore file two weeks ago, changes to it haven't been tracked, so when I do a stash, pull, and unstash, my changes over the past two weeks are gone.  How do I keep my changes when I stash and unstash files that are gitignored?

Comment: If the files are machine specific configurations, the correct course of action would be to enforce that no one on the team is pushing them. That way everyone has their own set of configs, but no one interfears with the others.

Comment: And if they are machine specific/user specific, you can gain some safety by putting a hostname or username in the filenames (and updating any code that uses the file accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

Don't put them on your gitignore. If you want to hide some file use:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```